Want to understand what is the issue if I using my configuration in CDN /*
I want to understand, my website www.example.com is behind CDN, I am using S3 bucket to fetch the image files.
When any end user to trying to fetch any image(jpeg) file the path will be
www.example.com/image/s3.amazonex1.com/abc.jpeg
www.example.com/image/s3.amazonex2.com/abc.jpeg
www.example.com/image/s3.amazonex3.com/abc.jpeg
now in my CDN I am configuring host/image/*
so what is the issue here?
I want to understand if any security issue also, or any other configuration issue?
what should be changed in the CDN configuration
